# How to apply decorators to Cython cpdef functions

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I've been playing around with Cython lately and I came across this error when applying a decorator to a Cython function

`Cdef functions/classes cannot take arbitrary decorators`

Here is the code I was tinkering with:

```
import functools

def memoize(f):
    computed = {}
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def memoized_f(main_arg, *args, **kwargs):
        if computed.get(main_arg):
            return computed[main_arg]
        computed[main_arg] = f(main_arg, *args, **kwargs)
        return computed[main_arg]
    return memoized_f

@memoize
cpdef int fib(int n):
    return 1 if n < 2 else fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

The error suggests that cdef functions can only take *certain* decorators. Is it possible to write your own decorators that you can apply to cdef functions?

---

EDIT: For future readers:

The `g = plus_one(_g)` trick mentioned in @DavidW's answer *sort of* works. It does not work with recursion. e.g. doing `fib = memoize(fib)` in my example code does not memoize the recursive calls to fib, although it does memoize the top-level call. i.e. calling `fib(5)` will memoize the result of the `fib(5)` call, but it will *not* memoize the recursive calls (i.e. `fib(4), fib(3), fib(2), fib(1)`)

As @DavidW points out, `cdef, cpdef` functions are fully determined at compile time; the decoration is a runtime thing and does not update the actual function.

Comment: Just a quick comment about my trick: note that I've used different names. If you name your `cdef` function `_fib`, did `fib = memorize(_fib)` and made sure you recursively called `fib` (not `_fib`) I think it would work, but you'd add a lot of Python overhead on each call.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**No** - you can't easily write decorators for `cdef` functions. The decorators `cdef` functions take are things like `cython.boundscheck` which control the Cython code generation rather than user generated functions.

The main difference between a `cdef` function and a `def` function is that a `cdef` function has a C interface while a `def` function becomes a Python callable so can be used from Python (but calling it is slightly less efficient because the arguments have to be passed in terms of PyObjects). [The inside of *both* a `cdef` and `def` function is compiled by Python so the only performance difference comes from the calling overhead]

The usual use of a decorator is to take an arbitrary Python callable and make some modification to it. For example

```
def plus_one(f):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
       return f(*args,**kwargs) + 1
    return wrapper
```

now try to use it on a cdef function

```
cdef int g(double x, double y):
    # some implementation...
```

The first problem is that g is translated to C code like `int g(double x, double y)` which can be represented by a function pointer but not as an arbitrary Python callable like `plus_one` expects. Second, `wrapper` has no way of knowing (from a C function pointer) what `g`s arguments are called (can't do `**kwargs`) or any easy way of doing the `*args` expansion.

You can make something like a decorator by taking a specific function pointer type and returning a Python callable:

```
cdef plus_one(int (*f)(double, double):
    def wrapper(double x, double y):
       return f(x, y) + 1
    return wrapper

cdef int _g(double x, double y):
    # some implementation

g = plus_one(_g) # kind of like a decorator
```

*However,* you've lost the whole benefit of using a `cdef` function since `g` is now a generic Python callable with all the overhead that goes with it.

---

Addendum: an alternative way of putting it is that decorators are a runtime Python feature (usually run at module import). `cdef` functions are a compile-time C feature. While it probably wouldn't be impossible to implement something like "compile-time decorators" it would be a pretty significant change to Cython.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the explanation.