# How to find a set of paths that cover all edges from source to sink in a DAG?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a directed acyclic graph (given by an adjacency matrix), a source node and a sink node. I would like to find a set of paths `P` of cardinality no more than the number of edges, from the source to the sink, such that for each edge `e` in the graph, there exists a path `p` in `P` that such `e` is in `p`.

My idea was to find all paths in the graph and as soon as I cover all edges I stop. I think this idea is not the best and probably there is a better way.

I started from [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46500318/9244653):

```py
def all_paths(adjm, source, sink, path, edges):
    # def covered(E, P):
    #     e = []
    #     for p in P:
    #         e.extend([(p[i], p[i + 1]) for i in range(len(p) - 1)])
    #     if set(e) == set(E):
    #         return True
    #     else:
    #         return False

    path = path + [source]

    if source == sink:
        return [path]

    paths = []
    for child in range(source + 1, adjm.shape[0]):  # I assume that the nodes are ordered
        if adjm[source, child] == 1:
            if child not in path:
                # if not covered(edges, paths):
                paths.extend(all_paths(adjm, child, sink, path, edges))

    return paths
```

Comment: How is this checking to see if all edges are covered?

Comment: See my edits. The code does not give the desired result, however. I am still debugging to find out why the covered function is not working.<

Comment: What is the issue, exactly, what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"a set of paths P of cardinality no more than the number of edges"*

Well, if you are allowed one path per edge, there is a very simple algorithm which works:

- Precompute paths from `source` to all other nodes using Dijkstra's algorithm.
- Precompute paths from all other nodes to `sink` using Dijkstra's algorithm but imagining that every edge goes in the opposite direction.
- Initialise `P` as an empty set.
- For each edge `u-v` in the graph:

  - Form a path by concatenating the precomputed path from `source` to `u`, then the edge `u-v`, then the precomputed path from `v` to `sink`.
  - Add this path to `P`.
- Return `P`.

The resulting set contains paths such that every edge is included in at least one path, by construction.

You can also improve the algorithm quite easily, by maintaining a set of edges used so far, updating this set when you add a path to `P`, and skipping `u-v` in the loop if it's already in the set.